# Convert seconds to Duration XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I convert time in seconds to a Duration string for example:

```
2 Days 10 Hours 10 Seconds
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: Honestly I don't know.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to do this in pure XPath, certainly I can't see how you'd do it in XPath 1.0, though it might be doable in 2.0.  What tool/library/programming language are you using to evaluate your XPaths and what version of XPath does it support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind seeing zeros in the output, you can use integer division and modulo operations to separate the value into hours, minutes, seconds, and days:

The number of seconds is the input value modulo 60. (Discard everything but the "second hand")

The number of minutes is the input value divided by 60, truncated to integer, and then taken modulo 60. (Rescale seconds to minutes, discard everything but the "minute hand")

The number of hours is the input value divided by 3600 (60 * 60), truncated to integer, and then taken modulo 24. (Rescale seconds to hours, etc.)

The number of days... you should see the pattern by now... divide by 86400 (24 * 60 * 60) and truncate to integer. Since we're not going to try to divide that up into months and years, we can stop here.

Untested but should work:

```
concat(floor($NUMSEC div 86400),' Days ',floor($NUMSEC div 3600) mod 24,' Hours ',
  floor($NUMSEC div 60) mod 60,' Minutes ',$NUMSEC mod 60,' Seconds'
```

where $NUMSEC is either an XPath variable which contains the total number of seconds or an XPath expression which returns that integers. Yes, the latter would be inefficient, but that's what you get for trying to do this as a single expression.

If you want to suppress sections which come out as zero and do it entirely within XPath 1.0... I think it's possible, but frankly that's uglier than I want to deal with so I'm leaving it as an  exercise for the reader.

(XPath 2.0 recognizes Duration as a datatype and has functions to access the Duration's components, so that's another option. To convert an integer to a duration, multiply it by the implied time unit, eg `PTS1`.)

HOWEVER: Possible does not equal good idea. Unless there is a reason that you *must* do this in XPath (trying to make it function as a more general macro language, perhaps?) I'd generally recommend just using XPath to retrieve the value and doing the conversion in whatever language you're launching the XPath from.

AND if you really do need an expression language which is good at formatting data as well as retrieving it from XML, I'd suggest you see if you can get your paws on XQuery. XQuery is in some sense a superset of XPath 2.0 which adds most of the same capabilities as XSLT 2.0, though in the form of query expressions rather than in XML syntax.

Comment: "I'm not finding an easy way to convert a raw number into a Duration" - just multiply the number by a unit duration like PT1S.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't thought about whether duration math was supported. That's too obvious.... Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 4):

You really need to say whether you are using XPath 1.0 or 2.0 - the answers will be quite different.

In XPath 2.0 you can convert to a duration using

```
$seconds * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')
```

and then you can extract the parts of the duration using

```
days-from-duration($d)
hours-from-duration($d)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with XML and XPath, which is what your question appears to be suggesting. However, assuming that you're restricting yourself to XML technologies, you could do it with XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="duration">
  <xsl:param name="seconds" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number($seconds) >= 86400">
      <xsl:value-of select="floor(number($seconds) div 86400)" />
      <xsl:text> day(s) </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="duration">
        <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="number($seconds) mod 86400" />       
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="number($seconds) >= 3600">
      <xsl:value-of select="floor(number($seconds) div 3600)" />
      <xsl:text> hour(s) </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="duration">
        <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="number($seconds) mod 3600" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="number($seconds) >= 60">
      <xsl:value-of select="floor(number($seconds) div 60)" />
      <xsl:text> minute(s) </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="duration">
        <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="number($seconds) mod 60" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="number($seconds)" />
      <xsl:text> second(s) </xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

(XSLT 2.0 has idiv, so you could do away with the floor(.).)